# Method of undetermined coefficients for ODEs to. find particular solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have hit a conceptual barrier. So let's say we had the following ODE:

$$\frac{d^{4}u}{dt^{4}} - 16u = te^{2t}.$$

The general solution of the associated homogeneous equation is:
$$u_h(t) = c_{1}e^{-2t} + c_{2}e^{2t} + c_{3}\cos(2t) + c_{4}\sin(2t)$$

Now to guess the particular solution, I was following the reasoning presented in class:

We try to guess $e^{2t}$ but it is part of the homogeneous solution, so we guess $te^{2t}$ but since this is the RHS, we go one power high, and our guess is $At^{2}e^{2t} + Bt^{}e^{2t}$.

I really just do not understand the reasoning behind this. Why do we care what the RHS is to increase powers? Why do we go one power higher than the RHS? Also how are these "guesses" being made?

Comment: Taking derivatives of a polynomial reduces the degree of said polynomial. Hence, you need to ansatz a solution with a polynomial degree _at least equal to_ the degree of the polynomial on the RHS, so that after taking derivatives your ansatz has the same form as the polynomial on the RHS.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: If all we need is to have a power that is at least equal to the. RHS, why not just choose $te^{2t}$?

Comment: Because $te^{2t}$ doesn't solve your problem. I said _at least equal to_ in my previous comment because I was considering other possible inhomogeneities, not just the one in your problem above. If you ansatz $u_{p} = Ate^{2t}$ and substitute into the LHS, you will find that the terms that go like $te^{2t}$ cancel (as, via the product rule, $u_{p}^{(iv)} = 16te^{2t} + Ce^{2t}$ for some constant $C$ and $16u_{p} = 16te^{2t}$) and so can't match the RHS. If you set $u_{p} = At^{\color{red}2}e^{2t} + Bte^{2t}$ however ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Rule to find the particular solutions:** To find the particular solutions of a differential equations with constant coefficient of the form
> $$f\left(y^{(n)},y^{(n-1)},\cdots,y'',y',y\right)=e^{αx}~G(x)~\tag1$$
> where $~G~$ is a polynomial of $~x~.$ Now
>
> $(a)~~$If $~e^{αx}~$ isn’t a solution of the complementary equation$$f\left(y^{(n)},y^{(n-1)},\cdots,y'',y',y\right)=0~,\tag2$$ then the particular solution of $(1)$ is of the form $~y_p=e^{αx}~Q(x)~,$ where $~Q~$ is a polynomial of the same degree as $~G~$.
>
> $(b)~~$If $~e^{αx}~$ is a solution of equation $(2)$ but $~xe^{αx}~$ is not, then $~y_p=xe^{αx}Q(x)~,$ where $~Q~$ is a polynomial of the same degree as $~G~.$
>
> $(c)~~$If both $~e^{αx}~$ and $~xe^{αx}~$ are solutions of equation $(2)$, then $~y_p=x^2e^{αx}Q(x)~,$ where $~Q~$ is a polynomial of the same degree as $~G~.$
>
> and so on.

---

Here complementary function is $$c_{1}e^{-2t} + c_{2}e^{2t} + c_{3}\cos(2t) + c_{4}\sin(2t)~.$$
Clearly here $~e^{2t}~$ is in the complementary function but $~te^{2t}~$ is not, i.e., it is a similar case that of option $(b)$. Therefore the particular integral is  $u_p=te^{2t}Q(t)=at^2e^{2t} +b te^{2t}~,$ as here $~G(t)=t~$ so take $Q(t)=at+b~.$

Now $~u_p~$ must satisfy $~(D^4-16)u=te^{2t}~,$ so putting the value of $~u_p~$ in the equation we have $~a=\frac{1}{64}~$ and $~b=-\frac{3}{128}~.$

Therefore the complete solution of the given differential equation is $$u(t)=c_{1}e^{-2t} + c_{2}e^{2t} + c_{3}\cos(2t) + c_{4}\sin(2t) + \frac{1}{64}~t^2e^{2t} -~\frac{3}{128}~te^{2t}~.$$

---

For more such rule you must see the note [The Method of Undetermined Coefficients](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Book%3A_Elementary_Differential_Equations_with_Boundary_Value_Problems_(Trench)/05%3A_Linear_Second_Order_Equations/5.04%3A_The_Method_of_Undetermined_Coefficients_I).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of seeing what is behind these guesses is to use the annihilator polynomial method. You want to solve an equation of the form $P(D) y = f(t)$, where $P$ is a polinomial in the differentiation operator. (for instance, the dif. eq. $y'''+y''-y = e^t$ would be written as $(D^3+D^2-1)y = e^t$). If you are able to find a polynomial $Q(D)$ such that $Q(D) f(t)=0$, the original equation can be reduced to
$$
P(D) y = f(t) \Rightarrow Q(D)P(D) y = 0.
$$

So, you reduce the original equation to an homogeneous equation with higher degree (of coarse this is not possible for all $f$, just for the ones that can be a solution to an homogeneous equation).

The solution to this higher degree but homogeneous problem is obtained and decomposed in two parts: i. the general solution to the original homogeneous equation; ii. the rest.

The "rest" is what you should use as a particular solution.